# angularFire Firebase get object keys

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2

I have a list in which i also have object named multiplayer

```
multiplayers
0YYbHk6Y1QORGEvOjvKW7DZATJs2
opponentId: ""
score: 3
ErgRlNCMtrVdlZW8hwdz44HiuHl1
opponentId: ""
score: 0
WlWCnCLca4TjpoBGodxXH3dkHxi1
opponentId: "ErgRlNCMtrVdlZW8hwdz44HiuHl1"
score: 0
```

i want the title, by that i mean `0YYbHk6Y1QORGEvOjvKW7DZATJs2` , `ErgRlNCMtrVdlZW8hwdz44HiuHl1` but cannot iterate over it because it is an object...

mainly i want the object key `WlWCnCLca4TjpoBGodxXH3dkHxi1`
which is next to `ErgRlNCMtrVdlZW8hwdz44HiuHl1`(i have this key as the current user id)

how would it be possible???

please help thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's not completely clear how you have that data. But if you have it as a JSON object, you can iterate over its keys with `Object.keys()`.

```js
var json = {
  multiplayers: {
   0YYbHk6Y1QORGEvOjvKW7DZATJs2: {
      opponentId: "",
      score: 3
    },
    ErgRlNCMtrVdlZW8hwdz44HiuHl1: {
      opponentId: "",
      score: 0
    },
    WlWCnCLca4TjpoBGodxXH3dkHxi1: {
      opponentId: "ErgRlNCMtrVdlZW8hwdz44HiuHl1",
      score: 0
    }
  }
}

Object.keys(json.multiplayers).forEach(function(key) {
  console.log(key, json.multiplayers[key]);
});
```